# Book about an artist/musician couple who move to a new cottage

Tags: identification-request

Looking to place a book read circa 2000 about a couple who move to a cottage in the country, where the woman was an artist and the man was a music producer (I think, bit vague now), and the man has a history of drug use. They meet a local man who had some kind of magical/supernatural power which he uses against them and I seem to think the cottage walls melted at some point. Version I had was a white cover with the cottage on it. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Literature, Liam! This is a good ID question, but there's some more details you might be able to add, such as how long was the book, where did you read it, what language was it originally written in. [We have a meta post with some suggestions and a checklist for ID questions.](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/779/17)